# Python tkinter add content to each tab

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am building an app in Python and I'm thinking of using tkinter to add tabs. I need 3 tabs: Current, Forecast, Settings. I built an app that returns weather information based on a zipcode or city name. I need the Current tab to display current weather, the Forecast tab to display the 3-day forecast, and on the settings tabs, I will add options for the app to change backgrounds, etc.
I am fairly new to tkinter and I'm not understanding how to add anything beyond labels and buttons to each tab. If anyone is able to point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. I've search for 'adding content to tkinter tab', adding methods and classes to tkinter tab' but haven't been able to find any resources.

This is what I've written so far to build the widget:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook, Label

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x350')
root.title('Weather Application')

weather_tabs = Notebook(root, padding=10)

main_tab = Frame(weather_tabs)
forecast_tab = Frame(weather_tabs)
settings_tab = Frame(weather_tabs)

weather_tabs.add(main_tab, text='Current Weather', state='normal')
weather_tabs.add(forecast_tab, text='Forecast', state='normal')
weather_tabs.add(settings_tab, text='Settings', state='normal')
weather_tabs.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

label_font = ('Arial', 24, 'normal')
label_main_tab = Label(main_tab, text='Main Tab', font=label_font)
label_main_tab.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2)

label_forecast_tab = Label(forecast_tab, text='Forecast Tab', font=label_font)
label_forecast_tab.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2)

label_settings_tab = Label(settings_tab, text='Settings Tab', font=label_font)
label_settings_tab.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2)

class my_class():
    text = 'Main Tab'

root.mainloop()
```

For the weather app itself, I used the model-view-controller structure and I'm pretty sure I'll have to make changes to the structure. The app prompts the user to enter their city name or zip code and returns a few bits of data from WeatherAPI which is displayed in the GUI.
This is what I currently have but I need to add the tabs and add this GUI plus two others:
[Current GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hHHA.jpg)

Thanks for any help/guidance provided.

Comment: You add other widgets to the tabs in exactly the same way you're currently adding labels - the first parameter to *every* widget is the parent container.

Comment: After I posted that question I went to bed and the answer you gave popped into my head. LOL. I guess I should delete this question. This was such a brain fart moment.